# SQL print title that contains character c, but c character mustn't be on the first or on the last place

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've already tried this:

```
select p.name as publisher, b.title, b.name as name_
from book b, publisher p
where b.title like '%c%'
and (b.title not like 'c%' or b.title not like '%c')
and b.idpublisher = p.idpublisher;
```

But it still prints out the title that contains 'c' on the first place
[as you can see on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G05AL.png)

What am I doing wrong?
PS: I'm using SQLdeveloper

Answer (score 2):

One method using `like` only would be:

```
where title like '%c%' and 
      title not like 'c%' and
      title not like '%c';
```

Another method would use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(title, '^[^c].*[c].*[^c]$')
```